# Can't install Ubuntu(Adaptec AIC-9410 Controller)

Tags: drivers, server

I have a server with Super Micro X7DB3 motherboard and Adaptech AIC-9410 controller. (http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/5000P/X7DB3.cfm). The latest driver I can find is for RedHat(CentOS) 5.4 and I can install(use "linux dd") CentOS 5.4 with the driver without any problem.

But I'd like to install Ubuntu 14.04LTS on this server, unfortunately Ubuntu can't find any hard disk. I think it need proper controller driver to work.

Can you please tell me where I can find the driver for this controller?
Or what to do to make this work for Ubuntu?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does anyone have ideas to make this server work? Any suggestions welcome.